# unable to get paypal post pramenters in the return url

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have one code for passing some custom variables to PayPal and these were collected in the return page, but when trying to get these values it is not working

I have a PayPal form like this :

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="image" src="submit.png" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"/>
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="IP"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="index.php?action=success"/>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="index.php?action=ipn"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Additional Information"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF"/>
</form>
```

I am successfully returning to the URL after payment. and there I am just trying to print the POST Variable for now and It is not giving me any values.I have tried by both enabling and disabling 'auto return'. In both case I don't get values.  Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying using a proper URL or your "localhost" server?

Comment: I am using proper url starting with http://

Comment: If 'these were collected in the return page' what do you mean by 'not working'?

Answer (score 0):

The "notify_url" will be contacted by paypal asynchronously (directly), without you having anything to do with this transaction. So you will never see in your browser any results whatsoever. You should use some kind of logging in your script to see what is actually being sent. Check your web server's access log to see if paypal is actually contacting your script (and make sure it's not "localhost" you're trying from)

Comment: I am able to get the values in notify_url, but I need get the same values in return url.

Comment: you can't, the return url is defined statically. If what you need is to get the form variables to both paypal AND your local script, then think of collecting them with javascript and posting them separately, before posting to Paypal

Comment: The return URL is specified as an HTML variable, not static, and rm=2 is supposed to post all the incoming POST variables back to it. See the IPN manual.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly only the transaction id is sent back to the return_url. The notify_url receives that id also. From there you should be able to communicate both pages to fill your needs.

Comment: I am not able to get any values, when I use print_r($_POST) in the page it returns me Array ( )

Comment: Sorry, If we enable PDT we will get the transaction id in the return url, after this we can use PDT for retrieving the details, I have followed instructions on https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer and it works fine for me. thank you for all.

Comment: rm=2 is specified as posting all the incoming POST variables back to the return URL. See the IPN manual.